# Is there posibility to disable "string templates"?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin have amazing, which is not present in java, but it is possible to do not use it somehow? Like for example in php:

```
"$foo"
'$foo'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't disable. But you can escape it using `\`.

```
val my_variable = "Some Value"
println("this --> \$my_variable")
```

Above code will print `this --> $my_variable`

Comment: Where is this documented ? I am confused :
From https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates 
"To insert the $ character in a raw string (which doesn't support backslash escaping) before any symbol, which"

But you are correct and it works..

Comment: Yeah, documentation is a little confusing. I think the document tries to convey that `$` (expression) doesn't support backslash escaping. e.g. "\$xyzVariable" -> "$xyzVariable".

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable them in any way. String templates are always interpreted, even inside raw strings, as the [related documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates) describes.

There's a way to input a literal `$` character, if that's your issue with it (described in the same docs). Otherwise, if you just find it odd or it's inconvenient for some specific use case, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: nice language :D `${'$'}` is best stuff I've ever saw

Comment: defining `val \`$\` = "$"` allows `"$\`$\`"` maybe you like that better ;)

Comment: @leonardkraemer its a little better actually thanks ! :)

Comment: No you can as @Suryavel TR pointed , how where documentation is misleading they stated you cannot. But I like escaping far more obviously and IT WORKS for ME ?? Why ?